# iOS Metal Unknown type name 'simd_half3'; did you mean 'simd_char3'?

Tags: swift, shader, metal, ios14

I'm trying to experiment with using smaller data structures to store Metal vertex data. The `Particle` struct is shared between Swift and Metal, but am getting the following error:

`Unknown type name 'simd_half3'; did you mean 'simd_char3'`

**What do I need to import to get over this compilation error?**

(The same struct compiles when pasted directly into the metal shaders file). Is it because there is no `half` type in Swift?

`ShaderTypes.h`  - C Header file

```
#ifndef ShaderTypes_h
#define ShaderTypes_h

#include <simd/simd.h>

struct Particle {
    simd_float3 floatTuple; // works fine
    simd_char3 charTuple; // works fine

    simd_half3 halfTuple; // Unknown type name 'simd_half3'; did you mean 'simd_char3'
};

#endif /* ShaderTypes_h */
```

All these types are defined in the same file, and using the command-click, I can jump to their definition (so the editor knows about the types), but I still get that build error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that there was no `Half` type in Swift until recently (there is `Float16` now with Xcode 12). But there still seems to be no `simd_halfN`, at least it's not listed in the `simd/vector_types.h` header.

The easiest option for you is probably to just work with `float` for now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `half` type in Swift, it's `Float16`. As for simd types, in Swift, `simd_floatN` is just a `typealias` for `SIMDN<Float>`.

It's defined like this: `public typealias simd_float3 = SIMD3<Float>`

Since Swift supports `Float16` now for half precision floats, you can just pass it to `SIMDN` generic, since it's defined as following (`SIMD3` for example)

`@frozen public struct SIMD3<Scalar> : SIMD where Scalar : SIMDScalar`

and there's an extension

`extension Float16 : SIMDScalar`

to make `Float16` conform to `SIMDScalar`

So you can use `SIMDN<Float16>` and if you want you can probably even typealias it in your code.

Comment: You provide great quality answers :) I'm still unable to cast, as Swift and it's precompiled headers are looking inside the include/simd.h, which does not have the concept of a "half" or "float16". The half type is defined in the "metal extended vector", which cannot be included. I also found there's something about the vector size and padding.

[ In earlier versions of the simd library, the alignment of vectors could
 *  be larger than 16B, up to the "architectural vector size" of 16, 32, or 64]
so a 8byte padded vector of 3 float16 will go against this.

Comment: Which platform are you on? I mean Xcode and macOS/iOS. `Float16` is pretty new, I think it only became available with Swift 5.3 but don't quote me on that. Also if you could copy the exact error you are getting that would be helpful. The availability for `Float16` is Xcode 12.0+, so yeah. Also, here's a documentation link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float16

Comment: I'm on iOS 14, the amount of type casting and conversions I'm seeing in all those examples that go back to iOS11 is quite large.